# iOS graph api issue (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks

this is my code for hitting the graph API for Facebook login. problem is program jumps directly to the end after the login manager. I have checked through break point it doesn't go into the block where the Graph is hit. Help would be really appreciated.

```
{
FBSDKLoginManager *Login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
[Login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult * result, NSError * error)
     {
         FBSDKGraphRequest * user = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,name,email,friends,gender" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
         [user startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection * connection, NSDictionary * result, NSError * error){

             if (!error)
             {
                              // Register * obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Register"];
                 //[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
                 NSString * str =[result objectForKey:@"id"];
                 NSString * email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
                 NSString * URL = [result valueForKeyPath:@"picture.data.url"];
                 NSLog(@"value ---- ,%@",str);
                 NSLog(@"email, %@",email);
                 NSLog(@"URL %@", URL);
             }
         }];
         }];
}
```

Comment: If `error`? It's async I guess, are your sure it doesn't pass in the block?

Comment: add the else condition of this if and write `NsLog@"%@,error"` its may be go in else condition so you can exactly found the error.